# Using a loop in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create multiple boxplots in ggplot.  I need to split my continuous variables by my nominal variable (School).  I want to omit single NA's in the data-frame dataSO.  I want to create a boxplot for every column and have the name of that column be the label.  When I use the following code I don't get an error message, but no plots are generated.  Any ideas?

```
for(i in 1:length(dataSO)) {
  boxplot <- ggplot(na.omit (dataSO), aes(School,i)) +
  geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "School", y = names(dataSO[i]))
}
```

I am able to generate one boxplot using this code:

```
box2 <- ggplot(na.omit (dataSO), aes(School, SOIRGlobal))
box2 + geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "School", y = "SOIRGlobal")
```

I would like to great boxplots for 9 other variables in dataSO which is

```
dataSO <- subset(datafull, Age >= 18, select=c(Age, School, Race, SOIR1:SOIR9))
```

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible data? It is often hard for others to see what one is trying to do.

Comment: almost certainly a `for` loop is not the right approach.

Comment: What @hrbrmtr said goes double for the situation where you are assigning to variable without indexing them to a multi-element strucutre.

Comment: you could look into using `face_wrap` to create plots like on [this page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html), but that would require transforming your data as well using something like `melt` from `reshape2` ([see here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/)).

Comment: In your loop, you create a variable `boxplot`, which will be a ggplot object, but don't do anything with it. Why do you expect output? Also, in your call to `aes(...)` the second argument, `i`, is an integer, not a column of `dataSO`. Provide at least a sample of `dataSO`.